# Best way to repair a model (3D xray model)

Tags: modeling, mesh

The standard format for this is dicom. I used a free converter to make a stl file out of it.
Unfortunately it didn't do the best.

Is there a way to repair this model, because redesigning it from scratch will propably mess up the proportions?

[image]

Comment: I see by an Internet search "dicom to stl converter" that there are a few free, and paid, converters. Is there any chance that using a different one would give you better results?

Comment: I used invesalius-3.1.1 
Maybe a different one will make better results, i will try it.